# Django passing from DropDownlist to View

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to get the value of the Drop-down Menu Selected. I have done the following and it is returning a 'null' value.

I think the problem is here: newupload = request.POST('nameProjects') but I'm not sure which on how to get it working.

upload.html

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="upload">
<select id="ddProjects" name="nameProjects">
    {% for project in projects %}
      <option value="{{ project.id }}">{{ project.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def upload_new(request):
    newupload = Upload()
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    newupload.project = request.POST['nameProjects']
    newupload.save()
return render(request, 'upload.html', {'projects':projects})
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a Django form?

Comment: But in the mean time, you're getting a string value and then attempting to call `save` on it. What, exactly, are you trying to save and where to?

Comment: And thirdly, the code you are using would have given you a clear error on the line you mention. You should *post* that error, but also try and understand and fix it yourself.

Comment: Error Message: 'QueryDict' object is not callable

Comment: The developer before me used HTML Forms and not Django Forms

Answer (score 0):

In the views.py, you should use request.POST['nameProjects'] because request.POST will give a dictionary.  If you want to store the project object in upload model, we need to give the project model instance variable or can give the id.

```
def upload_new(request):

    newupload = Upload()

    projects = Project.objects.all()

    newupload.project_id = request.POST['nameProjects']

    newupload.save()

return render(request, 'upload.html', {'projects':projects})
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I get this error: django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'nameProjects'"